# Package shinycssloaders causing dashboard to bounce

Tags: r, shiny, shinycssloaders

I use the package [shinycssloaders](https://github.com/daattali/shinycssloaders) to place loading bars in my dashboards while plots calculate. However, they appear to be causing the dashboard to [bounce occasionally when scrolled](https://gyazo.com/b57c0286235d9077cda87c22aca38590).

Obviously, this is undesirable. Does anyone know what could be causing this, and how I can fix it?

Reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shinycssloaders)


ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Example Bouncing Dashboard"),

    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 12,
        withSpinner(plotlyOutput("plot1", height = 600))
      )
    ),
    
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 12,
        withSpinner(plotlyOutput("plot2", height = 600))
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 12,
        withSpinner(plotlyOutput("plot3", height = 600))
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 12,
        withSpinner(plotlyOutput("plot4", height = 600))
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 12,
        withSpinner(plotlyOutput("plot5", height = 600))
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 12,
        withSpinner(plotlyOutput("plot6", height = 600))
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 12,
        withSpinner(plotlyOutput("plot7", height = 600))
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 12,
        withSpinner(plotlyOutput("plot8", height = 600))
      )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    graph <- mtcars %>% ggplot(
      aes(
        x = wt,
        y = drat,
        fill = cyl
      )) + geom_point()
      
    ggplotly(graph)
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({
    graph <- mtcars %>% ggplot(
      aes(
        x = wt,
        y = drat,
        fill = cyl
      )) + geom_point()
    
    ggplotly(graph)
  })
  
  output$plot3 <- renderPlotly({
    graph <- mtcars %>% ggplot(
      aes(
        x = wt,
        y = drat,
        fill = cyl
      )) + geom_point()
    
    ggplotly(graph)
  })
  
  output$plot4 <- renderPlotly({
    graph <- mtcars %>% ggplot(
      aes(
        x = wt,
        y = drat,
        fill = cyl
      )) + geom_point()
    
    ggplotly(graph)
  })
  
  
  output$plot5 <- renderPlotly({
    graph <- mtcars %>% ggplot(
      aes(
        x = wt,
        y = drat,
        fill = cyl
      )) + geom_point()
    
    ggplotly(graph)
  })
  
  
  output$plot6 <- renderPlotly({
    graph <- mtcars %>% ggplot(
      aes(
        x = wt,
        y = drat,
        fill = cyl
      )) + geom_point()
    
    ggplotly(graph)
  })
  
  output$plot7 <- renderPlotly({
    graph <- mtcars %>% ggplot(
      aes(
        x = wt,
        y = drat,
        fill = cyl
      )) + geom_point()
    
    ggplotly(graph)
  })
  
  output$plot8 <- renderPlotly({
    graph <- mtcars %>% ggplot(
      aes(
        x = wt,
        y = drat,
        fill = cyl
      )) + geom_point()
    
    ggplotly(graph)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This issue was discussed [here](https://github.com/daattali/shinycssloaders/issues/54) and should be fixed in the github version. I'm on version 1.0.0 from CRAN and I have no issues with your example dashboard in Firefox and Edge.

Comment: I am also using version 1.0.0 from CRAN and the issue persists. Attempting to install the remote version 1.0.0.~99 from github results in any plotlyOutputs within withSpinner() causing the error 'Error: 'ui_element' must be a valid Shiny tag.'

Comment: @anorlonda: Have you seen [this comment](https://github.com/daattali/shinycssloaders/issues/54#issuecomment-769496236) in the github issue. He is suggesting to set `height` or `min-height` for the spinners in CSS and it helped him resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following css style in app.R solves the issue.

```
tags$style(
    type = "text/css",
    "
      .loader {
        min-height: 40px !important;
      }
    "
  )
```